# Дозаписать файл Django

Tags: python, django, файлы

Есть модель Model у модели поле data типа FileFiled. Хранятся текстовые файлы.
Получаю модель:

```
model = Model.objects.get(id=1)
```

Затем достаю файл

```
file = model.data
```

Подскажите как дозаписать в него информацию.
Тип переменной file "django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile". Если применить метод dir, то метод write есть. Но когда пытаюсь написать

```
file.write('some string')
```

выдает ошибку:

> io.UnsupportedOperation: write

Пробовал разные варианты c использованием open

```
file.open(mode='w')
```

а если

```
temp_file = open(file, mode='w') 
temp_file.write('some string') # тут ошибка TypeError: invalid file:
```

Пробовал различные mod'ы.
Пробовал обращаться к полю FieldFile.file.

```
file = model.data.file
```

Получаю объект 'django.core.files.base.File' у которого тоже есть метод write, но с ним та же история.
Подскажите как можно дописать(дописывать) в файл нужные строки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так.

```
from django.core.files import File

model = Model.objects.get(id=1)

with open(model.data.path, 'w') as f:
    myfile = File(f)
    myfile.write('qwerty')
```

Comment: Спасибо. Сработало как нужно. Единственное mode пришлось поставить 'ab'. open(model.data.path, 'ab').